# Mybatis-Need to run dynamic query

Tags: mybatis

I am getting query from database.

Using that query I need to run that query and fetch data into collection.

Is there any way??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374054/how-to-run-arbitrary-sql-with-mybatis/13422329#13422329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used resultType instead of resulmap and some how I got desired output.