# How to run arbitrary sql with mybatis?

Tags: java, database, mybatis

I've an application that use mybatis for object persistence. But there are chances I need to run arbitrary sql(from user). Can I do it with mybatis?

**Update:**

I choose to use dbutils (JDBC) to run user-defined sql, but I need a instance of DataSource to create QueryRunner. Is there any way I can get datasource from mybatis?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use this utilitary class:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.SelectProvider;

public interface SqlMapper {
    static class PureSqlProvider {
        public String sql(String sql) {
            return sql;
        }

        public String count(String from) {
            return "SELECT count(*) FROM " + from;
        }
    }

    @SelectProvider(type = PureSqlProvider.class, method = "sql")
    public List<?> select(String sql);

    @SelectProvider(type = PureSqlProvider.class, method = "count")
    public Integer count(String from);

    @SelectProvider(type = PureSqlProvider.class, method = "sql")
    public Integer execute(String query);
}
```

Comment: @OrGal I'm using this class for a while in my apps. What (code) are you running to get this exception?

Comment: @italo, thank you for your answer, but doesn't it work for the sql file which has more than one sentence?

Comment: @Suge I never tested, but I think it won't work, because the MyBatis expect a result set. In this case you'll have more than one.

Comment: @italo, I find the way to solve it: add `allowMultiQueries=true` to the url, like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+databaseName+"?allowMultiQueries=true`

Comment: @ItaloBorssatto public List<?> select(String sql);    this  method not working, when i pass a entity to Generic,  eg:  List userList = mapper.<User>select("select * from user")

Answer (score 5):

Your question is similar to [How to exequte query directly from java code using mybatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152485/how-to-exequte-query-directly-from-java-code-using-mybatis)

I have already given the answer to that question. But I hope this solution will help you.

Mybatis has already this function, but you must use the adapter as follows.

1. create an adapter class;

   ```
    public class SQLAdapter {  
    String sql;  

    public SQLAdapter(String sql) {  
        this.sql = sql;  
    }  

    public String getSql() {  
        return sql;  
    }  

    public void setSql(String sql) {  
        this.sql = sql;  
    }   }
   ```
2. create typeAlias of class SQLAdapter

> `<typeAlias alias="sqladapter" type="com.zj.xxx.xxx.SQLAdapter" />`

3. put select tag in each object xml where you need to execute the sql directly.

   ```
    <select id="findRecords" parameterType="SQLAdapter" resultMap="xxxxxResultMap">  
        ${sql}  
    </select>
   ```
4. call this select method like

> ```
> String _sql = "select * from table where... order by... limit...";
> xxxxx.findRecords(new SQLAdapter(_sql));
> ```

5. Things have been all done. you can no longer write complex sql language in the xml file. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers provided, they both are good. But both of them required an `Adapter` class to be used.

Using *Mybatis version 3*, I succeeded using a `HashMap<String, String>` to keep and pass the *SQL*.

See the codes below.

in `Mapper` class

```
final String sql = "${sql}";

@Select(sql)
void execute(HashMap<String, String> m);
```

when invoke the method:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM record limit 1";
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("sql", sql);
mapper.execute(map);
```

`HashMap` provides a way that you don't have to define the Class properties, or fields in code, you can use a Map to define it redomly.

Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the following error in my mapper class when i perform maven build. any tips?

incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Comment: Do you know how to pass parameters into the dynamic query?

Answer (score 2):

Reusable fragment of SQL can be used to create select part of query dynamically. In you mapper pass query as normal parameter:

`@Param("sql")String sql`

In your query just access the parameter using ***${sql}*** instead of ***#{sql}***.
Value in parameter sql can be a fully valid sql query or a fragment of sql query.

Answer (score 1):

For testing I use

```
import org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
    
public class test {
        private static final String conf = "mybatis.conf.xml";

        private SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder;
        private SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Reader reader;
        private SqlSession session;
        private ScriptRunner runner;
       
    @Before
    public void before() {
        builder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();

        try {
            reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(conf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sessionFactory = builder.build(reader);

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        runner = new ScriptRunner(session.getConnection());
        runner.setAutoCommit(true);
        runner.setStopOnError(true);
    }

    @Test   
    public void testSelectChapelStatus() {  
        Reader populate = new StringReader("insert into person values (7553,0,'201002496','Wish','Jill','Rain',1,0,NULL,'xxx@LCU.EDU');\r\n"
                + "");
         runner.runScript(populate);
    }
```