# Passing an entire sql query as a parameter into a mapper in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I'm starting to use MyBatis with annotations and I tried to pass an entire query in a mapper like this:

```
public interface Mapper {   

    @Select("#{sql}")
    public HashMap<String,String> getResult(String sql);    

}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
String sql = "select * from table";
List<Object> list = session.selectList("getResult",sql);
```

When I executed the program I got this exception:

```
 org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #1 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
```

Comment: every modern framework has main goal to block sql injection. I'll be extremely surprised if Yoy will have effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because the sql string isn't a "sql parameter"! Instead, you can use this solution: [How to run arbitrary sql with mybatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374054/how-to-run-arbitrary-sql-with-mybatis)